# Resolve the equation $xy''-(x+n)y'+ny=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Resolve the equation $xy''-(x+n)y'+ny=0$

the first solution is easy $y_1(x)=e^x$ then by Reduction of order

$y''-((x+n)/x)y'+(n/x)y=0$ then $p(x)=((x+n)/x)$

$y_2(x)=e^x \int_{}^{} (e^x x^n)/ (e^x e^x)\, dx = e^x \int_{}^{} (x^n)/ (e^x) \, dx$ Is it a Incomplete gamma function??

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)

here I don't know what I should do

Comment: Yes it is an incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$xy'' - (x+n)y' + ny  = x(y'-y)' - n(y'-y) = 0$$
Let $y'-y = z$. We then get
$$xz' - nz = 0 \implies \dfrac{dz}z = n \dfrac{dx}x \implies \log(z) = n \log(x) + c \implies z = k x^n$$
Hence,
$$y'-y = kx^n \implies (y e^{-x})' = kx^ne^{-x} \implies y(x) = k e^x \int_0^x t^n e^{-t} dt + ce^x$$